# Concourse CI - continuously running job

Tags: concourse

I need a job in Concourse that runs continuously and fires triggers depending on a few different inputs. If the job crashes for whatever reason I need the job to restart.

Any suggestions? Do I need to add another piece like Nagios to check for the crash?

My current job is failing intermittently and I'm hoping I can find a restart facility within Concourse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concourse does not have a concept of a long running task.

It would be better to have concourse orchestrate the LRP (long running process), not run it. It could reach out to this LRP, update the config, and restart it on a remote server. My recommendation would be using `monit` or `systemd` to manage that LRP.